# Is there any opengl cel shading tutorial out there (without GLAUX)?

Tags: opengl

I want to implement cel shading into my opengl game. I have only found a nehe tutorial that uses glaux (old as hell). I'm looking into it, but I wanna avoid the pain of learning how to translate those old glaux functions/variables. Is there any cel shading tutorial out there that uses glut/sdl?

http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=37

Comment: OpenGL 1.X, OpenGL 2.1 with shaders, OpenGL ES 1.x or OpenGL ES 2.X?

Comment: You missed out GL 3.X. ;)

Comment: I don't need advanced GLSL for this effect! So toon shaders must be compatible with OpenGL 2.1 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should search Toon Shading too.

For english readers, [a short tutorial.](http://www.cse.unr.edu/~mahsman/courses/cs791a/)

For french readers, there is [a great tutorial](http://raptor.developpez.com/tutorial/rendering/celshading/).

Comment: English link no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1438.asp) an article explaining all the processes behind it, but not actually giving code.

Or there's the fact you also asked this on SO too, which is wasting everybody's time.

> Try the [Linux/GLUT](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/linux/lesson37.tar.gz) or [Linux/SDL](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/linuxsdl/lesson37.tar.gz)
>   versions. No glaux.h needed.
>
> The Visual C++ version doesn't seem to
>   actually use anything from glaux.h, it
>   just #incudes it.

Above quote from [genpfault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44729/genpfault).