# How do I create this type of mixed 2D/3D character model?

Tags: 2d, 3d, animation, flash, character

I'm interested in how [this little *Lively Hamster* Flash game](http://petgames.my-pet-care.com/hamster-games/lively-hamster.html)'s character is modelled and animated.

[image: screencap from Lively Hamster]

The head seems 3D. The back always shows a black outline, so I assume it is 2D.

Is this a Flash-provided effect? How could I create such a model?

Comment: Looks like a model that's been cel-shaded. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56541/how-do-i-create-a-cel-shaded-cartoon-look

Comment: I made some edits to clarify. It sounded like you intended to ask this as a conceptual question, so I removed the references to JS and Java. (If they're particularly important to you, feel free to [edit](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/101982/edit) them back in. Everything's still in [revision history](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/101982/revisions).)

Comment: I concur that it looks like a cel-shaded 3D model. Since this is Flash, this is probably using Away3D.

Comment: Yes, it is a conceptual question. I don't require a JS/Java based answer, the main reason I included those words was because I would like to know how it works instead of just it is xRandomFlashObject in Flash. If it is a pure 3D cel-shaded model, please add that as the answer. The main reason I asked this question was I didn't understand how there could always be a black outline to a 3D model regardless of its rotation, but I guess that would be answered by checking up how cel-shading works. Btw, I like the hamster gif :)