# How can I create a cel-shaded, comic book appearance in Unity?

Tags: unity, cel-shading

I am working in Unity, I have imported the post-processing stack and I own a license to [Amplify](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/visual-scripting/amplify-shader-editor-68570). But I'm having trouble making my models appear cel-shaded enough to make them appear as if they are from a comic book. I'd specifically like to achieve a result similar to that of Telltale's games like Wolf Among Us and Game of Thrones.

Here is a in-editor screen capture of the effect + shader values:
[image]

How can I get effects such as below?

[image: Bigby from Wolf Among Us]

[image: Game of Thrones TellTale]

Comment: I assume these screenshots are both examples of what you want to achieve? It would help us if you would show some of your own work for comparison, tell us what you did to achieve this and what bothers you about it specifically.

Comment: Corrected the spelling and added link, and yes, I will upload screenshots of what I have done asap!

Comment: The screenshots of what you want look very different from each other. In particular, the 2nd doesn't look cel-shaded at all. It's hard to tell what look you are actually trying to achieve, since the two examples you point to look quite different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a cel-shaded cartoon look?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56541/how-do-i-create-a-cel-shaded-cartoon-look)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've played with this in the past, and the answer to your question is two-fold:

1. You need appropriately designed assets. If you look at the big bad wolf from the Wolf Within Us, you will see that the texture for his model is stylised in cartoon form, as opposed to going for photo-realism. This is your first step.
2. Secondly, you need to change your rendering cycle. This is done by doing two render cycles: one for back facing polygons with thick lines, and a second normal rendering cycle using your cartoon textures, and using your attenuated light value to step the shading into three steps, instead of a continuous function. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cel_shading for some general information on this.

Comment: Tip, don't search for BBW on work computer. *Yikes*

Comment: Wow yeah, answer totally edited.